# Show 'All' along with page size in footer dropdownlist

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I am using Jqgrid in my project and wants to add 'All' along with page size in footer dropdownlist.So please let me know how can I show it.Also when user select All from dropdownlist it will display all the record.Please refer attached file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dropdown exist if you use `rowList` option. Mostly one uses array of numbers as the value of `rowList` like

```js
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [5, 10, 20, 10000]
```

jqGrid generates dropdown like

```html
<select class="ui-widget-content ui-pg-selbox" title="Records per Page">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
</select>
```

where the options have the same value and the text.

On the other side one can specify both text and values. One need just use `:`-separated string. For example

```
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"]
```

generates

```html
<select class="ui-widget-content ui-pg-selbox" title="Records per Page">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="10000">All</option>
</select>
```

which looks like

[image]

One can't require to display really **all** rows, but one can use large enough value like 10000 and show some text like "All" instead of 10000.